# Unable to Send Rich Text Email - Thymeleaf + Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, email, thymeleaf

I'm trying to send a rich text email using Thymeleaf + Spring 4. I've followed the example on Thymeleaf's website but for some reason it's throwing an exception.

Here is my config:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/mail/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    final Set<TemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new HashSet<TemplateResolver>();
    templateResolvers.add(templateResolver());
    templateResolvers.add(emailTemplateResolver());
    engine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
    return engine;
}
```

As you can see from the above config, I've two resolvers; one for the pages and one for the email template. Based on the research I've done online when I try to fire up an email using the template that I have, it is trying to use the templateResolver() instead of the emailTemplateResolver() although orders are set correctly.

Here is my email service:

```
Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);

/*
 * Send HTML mail (simple)
 */
public void sendSimpleMail(final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException {

    final String recipientName = "Name";
    final String recipientEmail = "Email";

    // Prepare the evaluation context
    final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
    ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);

    // Prepare message using a Spring helper
    final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
    message.setSubject("Example HTML email (simple)");
    message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
    message.setTo(recipientEmail);

    // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
    final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("email-simple", ctx);
    message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);

    // Send email
    this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);

}
```

Here is the exception that is being thrown:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Resource resolution by ServletContext with org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver can only be performed when context implements org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext [current context: org.thymeleaf.context.Context]
```

Has anyone had any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Switch the order of the `TemplateResolver`s in your configuration.

Comment: like the error says, have you tried `IWebContext` instead of  `Context`

Comment: @M.Deinum you mean the physical locations in the file or the setOrder numbers? If it's the setOrder I've already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @redflar3 in order to IWebContext I also need to pass and grab the request and response as well. I'll try that as a last resort since I've read online that it's not a best practice. But hey thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @Jail the order doesn't do anything as you are adding them to a Set yourself. You need to switch that or inject the list into the method to make the `order` property work (`templateEngine(List<TemplateResolver> resolvers)` and then inject it instead of creating the collection yourself). Also `/WEB-INF` is not part of the class path so you might have an issue using that as a location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I ran into this issue before and after some research I found a way around it. Change your Java config to something like this, **you will also have to move your html content to /WEB-INF/classes/mail/** because ClassLoaderTemplateResolver looks in the classes directory for your files.

```
@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("mail/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    final Set<TemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new HashSet<TemplateResolver>();
    templateResolvers.add(emailTemplateResolver());
    templateResolvers.add(templateResolver());
    engine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
    return engine;
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will help will work

```
      WebContext wc=new WebContext(request,response,servletContext,request.getLocale());//servletContext Spring Context
       MimeMessage message = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
       MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
       wc.setVariable("name", "abc");// If you want to pass params to Template
       final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("TemplateName", wc);
```